# How do i prevent a function from yielding the entire script?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am new to javascript. I cant find a way to do this anywhere.

I am expecting this:

```
function sendInChannel(channel, msg, MessageCount){
  for (let i = 0; i < MessageCount; i++) {
    channel.send(msg)
  } 
}
```

to not pause the entire script. This is a discord.js function, and i want it to send multiple messages at once instead of this function waiting about 0.1 seconds and yielding it.

Comment: Create new async function without await which would make channel send message and call it inside loop, loop will iterate through and call all function which would execute functions without waiting them for execution

Comment: Small note if you're new to JS: use the JS naming conventions. Classes are UpperCamelCase, variables and functions are lowerCamelCase, "true" constants use ALL_UPPER_SNAKE_CASE. So that `MessageCount` function parameter should be `messageCount` (and yes, that matters, because people familiar with JS will read your function and assume that `MessageCount` is a class, because you used class naming for it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Promises and **async/await** to make it asynchronous:

```
async function sendInChannel(channel, msg, messageCount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < messageCount; i++) {
    await channel.send(msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Async doesnt work in modules. It is required to be a module sadly. I will set this as the answer, because this works with the HTML javascript.

Comment: Writing `async` in front of a function doesn't magically make it "faster". In the original construct `channel.send()` doesn't appear to be `async`, so there may be nothing to `await`. However if it really is `async` and returns a `Promise` that was discarded intially, `await`-ing those one by one will make the code run slower.